# Interpreting regression model significance in R

Tags: r, regression, time-series, hypothesis-testing, multiple-regression

I am currently trying to create a regression model in R. I have a time series (ts_1).

I converted this TS to a df and set the name of the column to 'Sales':

```
ts_1_reg <- as.data.frame(ts_1)
colnames(ts_1_reg) <- c("Sales")
```

For a task I have to create seasonal dummies to build a model with. The data is monthly, and hence I have created 11 dummies:

```
M1 <- rep(c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),12)
M2 <- rep(c(0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),12)
M3 <- rep(c(0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),12)
M4 <- rep(c(0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),12)
M5 <- rep(c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),12)
M6 <- rep(c(0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0),12)
M7 <- rep(c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0),12)
M8 <- rep(c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0),12)
M9 <- rep(c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0),12)
M10 <- rep(c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0),12)
M11 <- rep(c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0),12)
```

I created a matrix with the sales data and the seasonal dummies:

```
ts_1_reg <- cbind(ts_1_reg,M1,M2,M3,M4,M5,M6,M7,M8,M9,M10,M11)
colnames(ts_1_reg) <- c("Sales","M1","M2","M3","M4","M5","M6","M7", "M8", "M9", "M10","M11")
```

When I create a linear regression model:

```
fitreg <- lm(Sales ~.,data =ts_1_reg)
```

And look at the summary of the model I see:

[image: Model Summary]

As you can see none of the seasonal dummies are significant. And the adjusted r-squared is incredibly low. I would argue this model is pointless (although this is all new to me)

My question is: is this model pointless and meaningless, or am I not recognising something significant?

Comment: You need to take the time-series (ie, non-independent) nature of the data into account.  That said, whether the model is "pointless" is a different issue than either statistical significance or R-squared.

Comment: I see. So would you say that this model alone is statistically insignificant? I appreciate this might be a simple question for a much more complex issue. I am just a bit lost with it all as it is new to me.

Comment: I would say fitting a model that does not include auto-correlation to data that is expected to be strongly autocorrelated is pretty pointless. Imagine you are selling swimwear. You'd expect high sales in summer and low sales in winter. Currently, you don't feed your model the information that if sales are low in January they are likely also low in February. Why are you not using dedicated timeseries models?